# ASP.NET Core Web API - How to get all employees that will end their leave in 3 days time from the current date

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

In ASP.NET Core-6 Web API Entity Framework, I have employee Leave Model as shown below:

```
public class Employee
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

}

public class LeaveApplication
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public PaymentStatus PaymentStatus { get; set; }   
    public bool? IsApproved { get; set; }
    public virtual Emmployee Employee { get; set; }
}
```

I want to get the list of employees whose Leave will end in the next 3 days, using **EndDate** and where **IsApproved** is true.

**Note:** I am using Entity Framework

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use a query like below :

```
var next3Day = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(4);
var employees = context.LeaveApplications
              .Where(r=> r.IsApproved == true && r.EndDate > DateTime.Now && r.EndDate < next3Day).Select(r=> r.Emmployee )
              .ToArrayAsync();
```

Comment: _r.EndDate >= DateTime.Today && r.EndDate < DateTime.Today.AddDays(4)_ should be more appropriate